# Regex to match all strings of given format with given exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm really struggling with this one. I tried to search from left to right, but still can't figure this out.

I have a list of strings with random amount of tags, each placed in brackets, randomly positioned within each string. Few examples may look as follows.

```
[tag1][tag4] Desired string - with optional dash [tag10]
[tag1][tag2][tag3] Desired string [tag10]
[tag3][tag1][tag2][tag5] Desired - string (with suffix)
[tag2][tag5][tag4] [Animation] Target string [tag10]
[tag3][tag1][tag5][tag10][Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to extract from each string the content without tags, which are enclosed in brackets. The only exception is tag **[Animation]** or **[Animations]**. In case, one of these tags appear, I want to extract them as well together with the desired string.

So in case of list above, the desired output would be following. (I don't care about the whitespace around extracted strings, it will be trimmed afterwards.)

```
Desired string - with optional dash
Desired string
Desired - string (with suffix)
[Animation] Target string
[Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)
```

Originally, I was using as simple regex as `\[.*?\]`. Which matched all tags in brackets, and I simply replaced everything with empty string.

```py
re_pattern = r"\[.*?\]"
re.sub(re_pattern, '', dirty_string).strip()
```

However, now I found a need to have an exception for tags **[Animation]** and **[Animations]**, and really can't figure it out. Your help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match the first bracket only if it isn't followed by the tags you don't want:

```py
import re

lines = '''\
[tag1][tag4] Desired string - with optional dash [tag10]
[tag1][tag2][tag3] Desired string [tag10]
[tag3][tag1][tag2][tag5] Desired - string (with suffix)
[tag2][tag5][tag4] [Animation] Target string [tag10]
[tag3][tag1][tag5][tag10][Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)'''.splitlines()

for line in lines:
    print(re.sub(r'\[(?!Animations?\]).*?\]', '', line).strip())
```

Output:

```
Desired string - with optional dash
Desired string
Desired - string (with suffix)
[Animation] Target string
[Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a function as replacement for [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: def repl(match):
   ...:     if match.group(1) in ('Animation', 'Animations'):
   ...:         return match.group(0)
   ...:     return ''
   ...: 


In [3]: data = """
   ...: [tag1][tag4] Desired string - with optional dash [tag10]
   ...: [tag1][tag2][tag3] Desired string [tag10]
   ...: [tag3][tag1][tag2][tag5] Desired - string (with suffix)
   ...: [tag2][tag5][tag4] [Animation] Target string [tag10]
   ...: [tag3][tag1][tag5][tag10][Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)
   ...: """
   ...: print(re.sub(r"\[([^]]+)\]", repl, data))

 Desired string - with optional dash 
 Desired string 
 Desired - string (with suffix)
 [Animation] Target string 
[Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)
```

Make your regexes dumber and put logic in Python.

---

Note that this can be used in much more complicated situations. You can have a relatively simple regex finding the important points in the text and then have simple Python code getting some "parsed" data from the match object to do what you want... the function could even keep some state between calls for complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the better `regex` module with the following expression:

```
\[Animations?\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[[^][]+\]\h*
```

In `Python`, this could be

```
import regex as re

data = """
[tag1][tag4] Desired string - with optional dash [tag10]
[tag1][tag2][tag3] Desired string [tag10]
[tag3][tag1][tag2][tag5] Desired - string (with suffix)
[tag2][tag5][tag4] [Animation] Target string [tag10]
[tag3][tag1][tag5][tag10][Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'\[Animations?\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\[[^][]+\]\h*')

print(pattern.sub("", data))
```

And would yield

```
Desired string - with optional dash 
Desired string 
Desired - string (with suffix)
[Animation] Target string 
[Animations](prefix)Desired - string (and suffix)
```

The `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism shortly explained:

```
something_boring|even_more_boring(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(interesting)
```

For more information, have [**a look here**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Comment: Good explanation on the role of SKIP/FAIL is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912/1655567).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
(?:\[Animations?\]|(?<=\]))[^\[\r\n]+
```

- `(?:` - start a non-capturing group so we can make use of boolean "or"

  - `\[Animations?\]` - capture `[Animation]` or `[Animations]`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<=\])` - behind me is a closing bracket, `]`
- `)` - close non-capturing group
- `[^\[\r\n]+` - capture everything which is not an opening bracket nor newline

https://regex101.com/r/KQE4ak/1

Do note that this will capture the space which rests between `[tag4] [Animation]`

Comment: It gets the matches in the question +1 but it might have unintended side effects but I think that is unclear in the question so far. See https://regex101.com/r/QuGwns/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Hmm, good point. Thanks for that. Looking closer at the question, I think OP is expecting to use `.strip()` so my regex is not useful for that method...